# Modulo of two 32-byte numbers

Tags: python, c++, endianness, bigint

I have 2 big numbers (32 bytes each), the container which holds them is defined as follows:

```
struct key {
    unsigned char & operator[](int i) {
        return bytes[i];
    }
    unsigned char operator[](int i) const {
        return bytes[i];
    }
    bool operator==(const key &k) const { 
        return !memcmp(bytes, k.bytes, sizeof(bytes)); 
    }
    unsigned char bytes[32];
};
```

Тhis code snippet is taken from the [monero](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/ringct/rctTypes.h#L77) source code.

I need to work in a little endian byte ordering.

I want to  implement a modulo function which takes two keys `a` and `b` and returns the modulo operation `a % b`, again in a little endian byte ordering.

I am unaware of a good/efficient solution to the above which does not manually shifting and doing bit-wise operations on the numbers.

I thought of converting the char arrays into a Python datatype, performing the calculation in Python, and then returning the solution.

Is this a decent approach? What is the best way to embed Python code in C++?

Comment: So, which question do you want an answer to?    Do you want advice on options to compute the modulo in C++, or do you want advice on how to "embed" python code into C++?

Comment: Calling python code from c++ for such low level tasks seems like a bad idea. This is the opposite of what we usually want to accomplish with inter language calls.

Comment: If there is an efficient and rather easy way to compute the modulo in c++ i guess it's better.

Comment: Are the numbers signed or unsigned?

Comment: The numbers are Unsigned.

Comment: better use a bigint library, like: https://sercantutar.github.io/infint/ or https://github.com/connormanning/little-big-int or https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/ and lot other options

Comment: Using Python integers certainly will work as integers in Python are unbound, but the complexity of embedding Python *just to compute the modulus* is definitely overkill. Have you tried looking at the [CPython implementation for unsigned long integer division with remainder](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4d12e4dc28b7c782c368bae2e8fd3815167ed37d/Objects/longobject.c#L2703-L2828), which underpins the Python modulus operation for your class of numbers?

Comment: The comments happen to reference Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming, Vol. 2, which is an excellent place to look for such things. 4.3.2 is the chapter on arbitrary precision integer modulus.